# python requests libarary versions

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a python 3 script that runs correctly with requests version 2.4.3. I have a different version on a Mac and the script doesn't run. The version on my Mac is 2.18.3. I believe I installed both with pip3. Version 2.18.3 gives the following error.

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Header value 14396077 must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'int'>
```

Comment: you should use a virtualenv so you can be as specific as you like with dependencies

Comment: Also, you can just use `str()` method to convert the int value ;)

Comment: I just added the str() method now the server replies with request contains an invalid token. Can I not remove 2.18.3 and install 2.4.3? Looks like the api is wanting an int.